# How to configure Munin to montior Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008, munin

Is it possible to configure Munin to montior Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

On Windows 2003 Server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like it is possible based on the following.

There are a few [plugins available](https://redmine.koumbit.net/projects/munin-contrib/repository/revisions/d055f33780344d06d0673127716ba714aaabe01a/show/plugins/mssql) that seem to be designed to monitor MS SQL.

So if you are happy with setting up custom plugins as hinted at in [munin-node-configure help on their wiki](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToMonitorWindows) and have a basic Munin node installed on the Windows Server runing the MSSQL system.

I must confess that I have not tried to get this setup working yet, I am looking into the possibility of doing so though so if I find out more I will try to come back and update my answer.